# why getting (not%20set)&utm_medium=(not%20set) in install referrer value?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

When i click on firebase dynamic link then first open chrome browser then redirect to play store and after i install app using android studio that case i am getting install referrer value utm_source=(not%20set)&utm_medium=(not%20set) instead of actual value.

i want below install referrer value:

slug=xyzabc&password=*******

Comment: HI, did you get any solution, i'm also facing the same issue.